# How to guarantee bits of char and short for communication to external device

Tags: c++, cross-platform, serial-port

Hello I am writing a library for communicating to an external device via rs-232 serial connection.

Often I have to communicate a command that includes an 8 bit = 1 byte character or a 16 bit = 2 byte number. How do I do this in a portable way?

**Main problem**

From reading other questions it seems that the standard does not guarantee 1byte = 8bits,
(defined in the Standard $1.7/1)

> The fundamental storage unit in the C
>   + + memory model is the byte. A byte is at least large enough to contain
>   any member of the basic execution
>   character set and is composed of a
>   contiguous sequence of bits, the
>   number of which is
>   **implementation-defined**.

How can I guarantee the number of bits of char?  My device expects 8-bits exactly, rather than at least 8 bits.

I realise that almost all implementations have 1byte = 8 bits but I am curious as to how to guarantee it.

**Short->2 byte check**

I hope you don't mind, I would also like to run my proposed solution for the short -> 2 byte conversion by you. I am new to byte conversions and cross platform portability.

To guarantee the the number of bytes of the short I guess I am going to need to need to

1. do a sizeof(short). If sizeof(short)=2 Convert to bytes and check the byte ordering (as [here](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2091.asp))
2. if sizeof(short)>2 then convert the short to bytes, check the byte ordering (as [here](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2091.asp)), then check the most significant bytes are empty and remove them?

   *Is this the right thing to do*? Is there a better way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, communication with the serial port is somehow platform/OS dependent, so when you write the low level part of it, you'll know very well the platform, its endianness and CHAR_BIT. In this way the question does not have any sense.

Also, don't forget that UART hardware is able to transmit 7 or 8 bit words, so it does not depend on the system architecture.

**EDIT:** I mentioned that the UART's word is fixed (let's consider mode 3 with 8 bits, as the most standard), the hardware itself won't send more than 8 bits, so by giving it one `send` command, it will send exactly 8 bits, regardless of the machine's CHAR_BIT. In this way, by using one single `send` for `byte` and

```
unsigned short i;
send(i); 
send(i>>8);
```

you can be sure it will do the right thing.
Also, a good idea would be to see what exactly `boost.asio` is doing.

Comment: Yes, I think your right.  I am using the boost.asio library to do the low-level communication so this didn't occur to me.  Would it be true that a user on a system with char = 16 bits would not be able to use the library?  If I requested it to send the letter 'a' this would be twice the number of bits as my device expects?

Comment: Thank you, I'm still a bit confused though (sorry).  So from a char=16 bit implementation: char c = 'a'; send(c); would send half of the character?  Is is possible to convert the 16 bit character into an 8 bits to send the bits that my device expects?

Comment: @Tom: `a` is ASCII character 0x61, and it will always fit in 8 bits. If CHAR_BIT is larger than 8, the higer bits will be zeros.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/11781/) seems to suggest you can use `CHAR_BIT` from `<climits>`. [This page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/) even suggests 8 is the minimum amount of bits in a `char`... Don't know how the quote from the standard relates to this.

For fixed-size integer types, if using MSVC2010 or GCC, you can rely on C99's `<stdint.h>` (even in C++) to define `(u)int8_t` and `(u)int16_t` which are guaranteed to be exactly 8 and 16 bits wide respectively.

Answer (score 1):

`CHAR_BIT` from the `<climits>` header tells you the number of bits in a char. This is *at least* 8. Also, a `short int` uses at least 16 bits for its value representation. This is guaranteed by the minimum value ranges:

```
type             can at least represent
---------------------------------------
unsigned char             0...255
signed char            -127...127
unsigned short            0...65535
signed short         -32767...32767
unsigned int              0...65535
signed int           -32767...32767
```

see [here](http://jk-technology.com/c/inttypes.html)

Regarding portability, whenever I write code that relies on CHAR_BIT==8 I simply write this:

```
#include <climits>

#if CHAR_BIT != 8
#error "I expect CHAR_BIT==8"
#endif
```

As you said, this is true for almost all platforms and if it's not in a particular case, it won't compile. That's enough portability for me. :-)

Comment: Yes, I like your check on the size.  I will use this, thank you.